# How do I drop items in a specific location?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I planned on dropping some gems for my treasure hoard in an open box that used to hold ingredients and is not activatable; however, they didn't drop into the box.  Instead, they dropped all around me. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 7):

You can drag items where you want them to be by holding your action key (PC default: <kbd>e</kbd>), although there is a bug that causes them to go back to where they were dropped - to avoid it, leave the area after dropping items and re-enter it before dragging them.

Other than that, there is no way for the game to telepathically determine where you want the items to go and put them there.

Comment: I have an xbox 360 but thanks

Comment: @firedragon04 on PS3 this is possible by holding `X`, therefore on xBox it's probably possible by holding down `A` whilst pointing at an object.

Comment: @firedragon04 in that case substitute 'e' for whichever button you use to pick up items.

Comment: It wouldn't need to be telepathic - there is actually a reticle in the center of the screen, which would be an intuitive way for the player to indicate where they would like an item dropped. Of course it doesn't work this way, but a mod could take advantage of that without too much difficulty.

Comment: @BigDave There are no mods on xbox

Comment: This mod is PC only, but, seems to simplify item positioning:  [Jaxonz Positioner](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/52583/?)